# error when trying to run a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, server, composer-php, laravel-8

I am just getting started with Laravel and I wanted to download and run a project from github, but after running the php composer install and php artisan serve commands and going to http://127.0.0.1:8000, it says "500 Server Error". Do you guys have any idea what I should do in order to be able to run it?

Comment: The console where you ran `artisan serve` should show an error message.

Comment: Is there logs in the project that we can take a look at ? no errors in console ?

Comment: Did you make .env file?

Comment: it doesn't show any errors

Comment: @parastoo there is a .env.example file... should i modify something in it?

Comment: Yes , copy and paste this file in same directory, with new name " .env"

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.  You can also check the Laravel logs located in `storage/logs`

Comment: @parastoo now i got some errors because of the database and i think it's because i have to migrate it first. is it enough if i create a database with the same name that is given in the DB_DATABASE key from the .env file and then migrate it?

Comment: Yes please add your database information and after that migrate it @user14769698

Comment: @user14769698 this should help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IQYoAHqU7E

Answer (score 0):

Did you make an env file? You need to make sure your framework is connected to the server. You should have an env.example file to copy from and it should look something like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST="db"
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=YOUR DATABASE NAME
DB_USERNAME=YOUR DATABASE USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD
```

Save it in your root directory as .env

Answer (score 0):

First Form .env File Make APP_DEBUG=true.(then you will find error instead of 500)
If There is no vendor Folder than in Cmd Write Composer Update.
Then try php artisan serve